# entering a VBA array formula that is too long

Tags: arrays, vba, formula

Hi I'm trying to insert a formula array this way

```
Dim F1 As String
Dim f2 As String

F1 = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(rptEURegThresholds!C[7]=""Yes"",IF(rptEURegThresholds!C[16]=""No"",IF(rptEURegThresholds!C[15]=""Total Disclosure"",1,1"
f2 = "MATCH(rptEURegThresholds!C[-1],rptEURegThresholds!C[-1],0)))),ROW(rptEURegThresholds!C[-1])-ROW(rptEURegThresholds!R[-6]C[-1])+1)>0))"

With sh8.Range("F7")
    .FormulaArray = F1
    .Replace "1,1", f2, xlPart
End With
```

But something is wrong and can't find the issue. Please help!!!

Comment: Does it give you an error message? if so, what is the message and line it says there is an error on?

Answer (score 0):

I could think of 2 problems in the formula

1. Total no of characters in your formula ( including both F1 & F2) is around 272, which exceeds 255 characters limit of formulaArray in Excel  Kindly refer SO post  **[Overcoming the 255 char. limit for formulaArray in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025697/overcoming-the-255-char-limit-for-formulaarray-in-excel-vba)**.
2. The code is bound to halt at the line

   .FormulaArray = F1

   with error “unable to set the FormualArray property of the range class”
   As formula is incomplete at this stage (mismatches in parenthesis etc).

So I tried with shortening the Worksheet name from “rptEURegThresholds” to “rptEURT” and combining both F1 & F2 strings as F1. It worked without any error. However correct working of the formula may please only be checked by you.

```
Dim F1 As String

 F1 = "=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(rptEURT!C[7]=""Yes"",IF(rptEURT!C[16]=""No"",IF(rptEURT!C[15]=""Total Disclosure""," & _
    "MATCH(rptEURT!C[-1],rptEURT!C[-1],0)))),ROW(rptEURT!C[-1])-ROW(rptEURT!R[-6]C[-1])+1)>0))"


    With Sheets(3).Range("F7")
        .FormulaArray = F1
    '    .Replace "1,1", f2, xlPart
    End With
```