# Index Match FormulaArray concatenating dynamic array range in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having trouble with an Excel VBA formula array with a dynamic last row. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong here.

```
With wsres
    sou2 = .ListObjects("Table_OutputData2_1").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2&B2&D2,""Match"",""Not Found""),""WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("F2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("G2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(B2,SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & ",0))=B2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("H2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(D2,SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=D2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("E2:H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:H" & sou2)
End With
```

The error is: Unable to Set formula array property to Range Class for the below line of code:

```
.Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2&B2&D2,""Match"",""Not Found""),""WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in SourceDataSpread"")"
```

These lines of code works:

```
    With wsres
    sou2 = .ListObjects("Table_OutputData2_1").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    .Range("F2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("G2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(B2,SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & ",0))=B2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("H2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(D2,SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=D2,""Match"",""No Match""),""No Match to Both OutputData2 and SourceDataSpread"")"
    .Range("E2:H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:H" & sou2)
End With
```

I was able to run the code above by removing the FormulaArray with the concatenated arrays but I'm not sure why I cant concatenate arrays using FormulaArray in Excel VBA.

Please help me Excel Masters. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I get an error with the MATCH function "You've entered too many arguments for this function.". Does it work for you if you manually enter it into the sheet?

Comment: @Toddleson It does work when I enter it manually in the sheet. I just replaced `sou2 and chr(34)` with the last row and the ampersand. I also tried to remove the Chr(34) and just add it like `&SourceDataSpread!` but doesnt work. I am not sure maybe I did mess up something along the way.

Comment: At a glance, the Chr(34) concatenations look off. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish concatenating three range addresses together delimited by a double quote. Chr(34) probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need to compare the return value by using INDEX and the return from MATCH when you can just test for `ISERROR(MATCH(....))` ?  That's making your formulas more complex than necessary.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff The converted excel formula `=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$204&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$204&SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$204,MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$204&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$204&SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$204,0))=A2&B2&D2,"Match","Not Found"),"Not match in both sheets")` works, just that when I convert it to a FormulaArray in Excel VBA it doesn't accept it. Is there a much better conversion of this formula in Excel VBA? Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @TimWilliams I havent actually considered that for a formula but I just want to know if concatenating arrays in index match works in FormulaArray. If it doesn't then I'll consider using your approach. Thanks!

Comment: That aside, it's not clear why you're using `"`  ( Chr(34) ) as a delimiter in your formula.  Did you mean to use `&` ?  If you `Debug.Print` the result of that concatenation does it look as you expect? `=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$204"SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$204"SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$204,MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$204"SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$204"SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$204,0))=A2&B2&D2,"Match","Not Found"),"WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in SourceDataSpread")`

Comment: @TimWilliams I'll try Debug.Print, But I also tried this `.Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2&B2&D2,""Match"",""Not Found""),""WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in SourceDataSpread"")"` still not working. However, I'll try to use the idea you gave if there is no solution.

Comment: @TimWilliams Fixed some of the errors in the code above: `.Range("E2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2&B2&D2,SourceDataSpread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & "&SourceDataSpread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & "&SourceDataSpread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2&B2&D2,""Match"",""Not Found""),""WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in SourceDataSpread"")"`, still no luck. It does return the same formula that I have in Excel in Debug.Print and works when I enter manually.

Comment: There is a length limit on FormulaArray of around 250 characters I think. Try naming your sheet with a short name and see if that fixes it.  Similar work-around posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025697/overcoming-the-255-char-limit-for-formulaarray-in-excel-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams Still no luck `"=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Spread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(38) & "Spread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(38) & "Spread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",MATCH(A2&B2&D2,Spread!$A$2:$A$" & sou2 & Chr(38) & "Spread!$B$2:$B$" & sou2 & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "Spread!$H$2:$H$" & sou2 & ",0))=A2&B2&D2,""Match"",""Not Found""),""WO Type found in OutputData2 but not in Spread"")"` I think this is a limitation that should be addressed?

Comment: What is the length of that output?

Comment: @TimWilliams 242, I'll try decreasing it more.

Comment: Still have a `Chr(34)` in there....  `...sou2 & Chr(34) & Chr(38) & "Spread!$H$2:$H$" &...`

Comment: @TimWilliams It worked!! Thanks again, I knew it was something in my code. I almost gave up there. Thanks you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your help. I think I am crosseyed right now haha. I'd like to upvote you but I still lack reputation. Thanks again!